# how to execute a .js file containing multiple functions, via react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a pre-existing .js file which contains multiple functions ( they call each other within the file) and event listeners.

How do i execute this .js file after elements have been rendered in the .jsx ?

I have tried  adding export statement to the bottom of the .js file

```
export const A = functionOne();
export const B = functionTwo();
```

and adding import

```
import {A} from './index'
```

in the .jsx file

but it still gives react error that functions are not defined.

I know the file with the functions works perfectly because previously it was being used in a basic html / .js combination to render the page elements.By using    at the bottom of the html

Comment: If not mistaken, if you use `()` it is already executing the function, so you can write it as `export const A = functionOne;` instead then `import {A} from './index'` for you to use it you can call `A()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exports.funcName`. I have called them in `useEffect` hook

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-sanne-mxz4z?file=/src/App.js)

### App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { funA, funB } from "./functions";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    funA();
    funB();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Functions.js

```
exports.funA = () => {
  console.log("This is from Function A");
};

exports.funB = () => {
  console.log("This is from Function B");
};
```

Comment: so i looked into useEffect and it brought me to this page(https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)  i am using class App extends  React.Component so according to that page i'm supposed to use componentDidMount(){ this.funA(); this.funB(); }

however this doesnt seem to work, there are no errors but it doesnt print on console, i even added a window alert and that doesnt pop either. what am i missing here?

Comment: nvm figured it out doesnt work if there is 2 componentDidmount